# How can I return a own type data in oracle stored procedure?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, nested-table, oracle-objects

I create a type data in oracle for a procedure.

procedure:

```sql
create or replace TYPE ROW_USER as object 
(
    ID                  NUMBER(4),
    ROLES_ID            NUMBER(1),
    FIRST_NAME          VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    SECOND_NAME         VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    FIRST_LAST_NAME     VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    SECOND_LAST_NAME    VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
    CC                  NUMBER(10,0),
    EMAIL               VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)
);
```

and:

```
create or replace type NESTED_ROW_USER as table of ROW_USER;
```

when I use this type data in an anonymous blockand it works.

```sql
set serveroutput on; 
DECLARE  
    ROWUSR NESTED_ROW_USER;
BEGIN
    select cast( multiset(select id, ROLES_ID, FIRST_NAME, SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, 
    FIRST_LAST_NAME, SECOND_LAST_NAME, CC, EMAIL from USERS where id =  1) as 
    NESTED_ROW_USER)
       into ROWUSR
    from users;  

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ROWUSR(1).id||','||ROWUSR(1).ROLES_ID||','|| 
    ROWUSR(1).FIRST_NAME);
    END;
```

block result:

```
Process PL/SQL exited successfully.
1,1,DIEGO
```

But when I use it in a stored procedure to return it, I get an error.

Procedure:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE outnested(ROWUSR OUT NESTED_ROW_USR)
AS
BEGIN
  select cast( multiset(select id, ROLES_ID, FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, 
  FIRST_LAST_NAME, SECOND_LAST_NAME, CC, EMAIL from USERS where id =  1) as 
  NESTED_ROW_USER)
    into ROWUSR
    from users;     
END;
```

error:

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 16:
PLS-00302: component 'NESTED_ROW_USER' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 11:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 14, column 16:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Why does it not return the value?

Answer (score 2):

Are you really trying to generate a collection that has the same number of rows as the `usarios` table with the same object values in every element of the collection?  That seems odd.

My guess is that you really want something like this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE outnested(p_FILAUSU OUT NESTED_FILA_USUARIO)
AS
BEGIN
  select FILA_USUARIOr( id, 
                        ROLES_ID, 
                        PRIMER_NOMBRE, 
                        SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, 
                        PRIMER_APELLIDO, 
                        SEGUNDO_APELLIDO, 
                        CC, 
                        EMAIL )
    bulk collect into p_FILAUSU 
    from USUARIOS 
   where id =  1;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. the collection doesn´t have the same number of columns that the **usarios** table.
I ran your proposal but it throw the same error:

'component 'NESTED_ROW_USER' must be declared'

Comment: @DiegoF - I'm confused.  According to your question, the object type has the same set of columns that you are selecting.  I assume all 8 columns exist in the `usarios` table.  The collection is just a collection of the object type.  Are you sure that the problem isn't related to the Spanish-English translation?

Answer (score 2):

I ran your DDL in an Oracle 12c database, substituting the venerable `EMP` table for your `usuario` table, and it seemed to work.

[Oracle EMP and DEPT tables](https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/the-emp-and-dept-tables-in-oracle/)

The only potential error I noted was that you included `from usuario` twice in your query: once for the multiset and once as the source of the outer `SELECT`.
I substituted `from dual` for `from usuario` at the end of the query.

I removed the `WHERE` clause for convenience; I'm assuming you would retain it.

Make sure that the `NESTED_FILA_USUARIO` type is owned by the same schema as the `outnested` procedure, or you will then have to include the schema name prefix and make sure there is a *direct* grant from the owner of `NESTED_FILA_USUARIO` to the schema of `outnested` (roles don't work within compiled PL/SQL).

```
create or replace TYPE FILA_USUARIO as object 
(
  EMPNO NUMBER(4),
  ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
  JOB   VARCHAR2(9),
  MGR   NUMBER(4),
  HIREDATE DATE,
  SAL NUMBER(7,2),
  COMM NUMBER(7,2),
  DEPTNO NUMBER(2)
);
create or replace type NESTED_FILA_USUARIO as table of FILA_USUARIO;
```

Here is the anonymous block:

```
DECLARE  
    FILAUSU NESTED_FILA_USUARIO;
BEGIN
    select cast( multiset(select EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO from EMP) as 
    NESTED_FILA_USUARIO)
       into FILAUSU
    from dual;  

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FILAUSU(1).EMPNO||','||FILAUSU(1).ENAME||','|| 
    FILAUSU(1).JOB);
END;
```

Here is the stored procedure, with a test:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE outnested(FILAUSU OUT NESTED_FILA_USUARIO)
AS
BEGIN
  select cast( multiset(select EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO from EMP) as 
  NESTED_FILA_USUARIO)
    into FILAUSU
    from dual;     
END;
/
declare
  filausu NESTED_FILA_USUARIO;
begin
  outnested(filausu);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FILAUSU(1).EMPNO||','||FILAUSU(1).ENAME||','|| 
    FILAUSU(1).JOB);
end;
/
```

The output was this:

> 7839,KING,PRESIDENT

And that's expected for this query.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use 11c and the twice **from usuario** works for the anonymous block so it supous to work in the stored procedure. i tried whitout the WHERE clause but get the same error.